# Multiple JSON payload to CSV file

Tags: csv, dataweave

i have a task to generate CSV file from multiple JSON payloads (2). Below are my sample data providing for understanding purpose

```
 - Payload-1

[
  {
    "id": "Run",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot Run"
  },
  {
    "id": "Walk",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot Walk"
  }
]

 - Payload-2 (**Source Input**) in flowVars

[
  {
    "Action1": "Run",
    "Action2": ""
  },
  {
    "Action1": "",
    "Action2": "Walk"
  },
  {
    "Action1": "Sleep",
    "Action2": ""
  }
]
```

Now, i have to generate CSV file with one extra column to **Source Input** with **ErrorMessage**  on one condition basis, where the **id** in payload 1 matches with **sourceInput field** then **errorMessage** should assign to that requested field and generate a CSV file as a output

i had tried with the below dataweave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=true
---
flowVars.InputData map (val,index)->{
        Action1: val.Action1,
        Action2: val.Action2,
         (
            payload filter ($.id == val.Action1 or $.id == val.Action2) map (val2,index) -> {

                ErrorMessage: val2.errorMessage replace /([\n,\/])/ with ""
            }
        )
}
```

But, here im facing an issue with, i'm able to generate the file with data as expected, but the header **ErrorMessage** is missing/not appearing in the file with my real data(in production). Kindly assist me.

and Expecting the below CSV output

```
Action1,Action2,ErrorMessage
Run,,Cannot Run
,Walk,Cannot Walk
Sleep,
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Payload-1" is `payload`, and "Payload-2" is `flowVars.actions`, I would first create a key-value lookup with the `payload`. Then I would use that to populate `flowVars.actions`:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv header=true

// Creates lookup, e.g.:
// {"Run": "Cannot run", "Walk": "Cannot walk"}
%var errorMsgLookup = payload reduce ((obj, lookup={}) ->
  lookup ++ {(obj.id): obj.errorMessage})
---
flowVars.actions map ((action) -> action ++ errorMsgLookup[action.Action1])
```

Note: I'm also assuming `flowVars.action`'s `id` field is unique across the array.

Comment: Hello Jerney, thanks for your response 
when i tried with your suggestion **Cannot coerce a :object to a :function** at %var lookup stage.

Comment: Oh, it's because I'm calling `errorMsgLookup` as a function on the last line, but it's an object. Edit includes fix.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the best way to solve this kind of problem is using `groupBy`. The idea is that you `groupBy` one of the two parts to use the join by and then you iterate the other part and do a lookup. This way you avoid O(n^2) and transform it to O(n)

```
%dw 1.0
%var payloadById = payload groupBy $.id
%output application/csv
---
flowVars.InputData map ((value, index) -> 
  using(locatedError = payloadById[value.Action2][0] default payloadById[value.Action1][0]) (
    (value ++ {ErrorMessage: locatedError.errorMessage replace /([\n,\/])/ with ""}) when locatedError != null otherwise value
  )
)
filter $ != null
```

Comment: Hello machaval, thanks for your response and it is working as like before, it can able to generate the file but in the input payload i have list of objects, and each object have min 6-8 fields.., still the **ErrorMessage** header is not updating in the CSV file.

Comment: You don't get this `Action1,Action2,ErrorMessage
Run,,Cannot Run
,Walk,Cannot Walk
Sleep,` as your output? Isn't this what you are trying to get?

Comment: i got the output as expected, but in the output CSV file **ErrorMessage** key is not updating and the values of ErrorMessage is updating as expected...

in prod i have huge data approx 10000 input., suppose in those if it failed 500., all errorMessages with respective ID it should generate the CSV file., i got the output as expected but the key/header is missing.